# Decode laravel 4 Input::json()

Tags: php, json, api, laravel, laravel-4

I am having a hard time decoding json input in laravel .. am building a Restful API and when i send post data using RestClient and then die and dump in laravel i got

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#205 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["firstName"]=>
    string(8) "John"
    ["lastName"]=>
    string(7) "Doe"
    ["bloodGroup"]=>
    string(2) "B+"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(8) "+9999999"
    ["address"]=>
    string(8) "Somecity"
    ["symptoms"]=>
    string(3) "Bla"
  }
}
```

Now i have tied to access the data using

```
$data = Input::json();
echo $data->firstName;
```

that does not work .. tried to convert it to array and then access 
like `$data['firstName']` does not work .

```
array(1) {
  ["*parameters"] =>
  array(6) {
    ["firstName"]=>
    string(8) "John"
    ["lastName"]=>
    string(7) "Doe"
    ["bloodGroup"]=>
    string(2) "B+"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(8) "+9999999"
    ["address"]=>
    string(8) "Somecity"
    ["symptoms"]=>
    string(3) "Bla"
  }
}
```

i want to decode the data then save it to db, Here is a tutorial building similar App ..

I have tried the post_index() method explained here but no luck .

http://maxoffsky.com/maxoffsky-blog/building-restful-api-in-laravel-part-2-design-api-controller/

Comment: As you can see `firstName` is inside of the `*parameters` array, hence can be accessed by `$data['*parameters']['firstName']`, however there's probably a reason that they're protected.

Comment: tried that too but no luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`->get()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/cd52e0a03042030d098cba652b901e3bbc5f7d7e/ParameterBag.php#L103) to access properties from a [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/cd52e0a03042030d098cba652b901e3bbc5f7d7e/ParameterBag.php) response.

```
$input = Input::json();
$input->get('firstName')
```

You can also get all inputs as an array and then type cast it to an object with [`(object)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Note that this will throw an error if your property doesn't exists, so if I where you, I would use the `->get()` method mentioned above.

```
$input = (object)Input::all();
$input->firstName;
```

Comment: that gives `object(stdClass)#205 (0) {}`

Comment: @user2202757, that means that your object is empty.

Comment: Well Input::all() returns an empty array

Comment: i used var_dump to see all the input data grabbed by Input::all() then it returns an empty array and error but if i use dd() then i can see the data .Strange problem .. But Thank you Input::all() works fine ....

Comment: @user2202757 you must set your request 'Content-Type' header to 'application/json' to see those inputs in Input::all() collection.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experiment

If you are sending an array of multiple objects like the following example from the Javascript using JSON

```
[{crop_id: 1, test_id: 6},{crop_id: 1, test_id: 7},{crop_id: 1, test_id: 8}]
```

You need to use **Input::json()->all()** function in PHP.

```
$arr = Input::json()->all();
$crop_id = $arr[0]['crop_id'];
$test_id = $arr[0]['test_id'];
```